# How do I crawl a website written in JSP (Java Server Pages) using Perl Script?

Tags: perl, jsp

I have here this website:https://www.connect2nse.com/iislNet/UserFolder.jsp
Firstly i tried using WWW::Mechanize, but it doesn't seem to work. WWW::Mechanize doesn't work with JSP written website. So I researched about how to download a file in a website written in JSP, but can't find a good one. Can anybody help me with this one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the client is concerned, JavaServer Pages is identical to PHP, Perl, or even static HTML files. The result is a page of HTML that can be rendered and displayed, and the source of the data isn't the reason for `WWW::Mechanize` failing to do what you want

***Doesn't work*** is useless as a problem description, and the issue could be pretty much anything. However, if the HTML is associated with some JavaScript (which is executed on the *client* system after the page has been retrieved and not on the server) then it may be more or less handicapped because `WWW::Mechanize` doesn't support JavaScript. For that you will need to use `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` or similar, which works by using a real instance of Firefox to render the HTML and execute any JavaScript